# Is Authlogic viable on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am looking for a good authentication solution. Is Authlogic the way to go for Rails 3? I am having problems and finding a lot of info that others are as well with Rails 3. Should I look at something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest Devise with Rails 3, it's well supported (and very slick). http://rubygems.org/gems/devise

Comment: Completely agree, its written by a rails core maintainer and is easy to read and create plugins for.

Comment: Great. I've been coming across that one in searches. Thank you.